# Симулировать запрос из браузера через postman

Tags: api, curl, header, auth

Здравствуйте задача следующая, нужно программно авторизоваться на стороннем ресурсе, заполнить и отправить форму(отправить нужный POST запрос). И потом из `Response Headers` извлечь хедер `Location`. Как бы работа по API но без API документации)

Я пытался импортировать `Curl` в `Postman` (Инспектор браезура -> Networking) и отправлять его но приходит ответ со страницей авторизации. Авторизация на ресурсе по логину и паролю. Возможно я не понимаю принцип авторизации ведь все куки также отправляются через `Postman`.

Если сумею сделать это через `Postman` то запрограммировать не составит проблем.

Comment: А какой тип авторизации? Через поля формы, BASIC AUTH, OAuth2? Вы написали, что нужно авторизоваться и отправить форму. Это одна операция (отправка формы для авторизации) или последовательность действий? Если можно, чуть подробнее.

Comment: @Vitaly нет сначала нужно авторизоваться, с этой стадией у меня все хорошо. отправляю вот такой запрос `curl -X POST \
  https://site.com.ua/login.php \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' \
  -H 'postman-token: d2797a8d-be72-5038-b2d1-174b2b5db6f5' \
  -F back=/index.php \
  -F email=xx@gmail.com \
  -F pass=grusf4444` А потом нужно отправить еще одну форму из респонса которой достать нужный хедер, но при отправке второй просит вход. BASIC AUTH, access_token-a нет

Comment: А что приходит в ответ на авторизацию? Через браузер же это работает, так? Значит токен приходит. Может сохраняется в сессии, может, в ответе приходит. Можно попробовать использовать расширение Postman Interceptor для того, чтобы запросы отправлялись через браузер.